# Freemarker template not displaying image

Tags: templates, freemarker

Is there a particular syntax for freemarker template to be used to display image?
I have used the usual

```
 <img src = "test1.png" />
```

in the body tag of the ftl template to display image but it is not displaying the image for me when I run the code. FTL generates the html page with all relevant data excpet that it doesnt display image.

SHould I use any escape sequences or any other syntax?

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer..
Its

```
<img src= "test1.jpg" />
```

just like I had added before. I wonder why it wasnt working earlier.